# SSL error on root domain name

Tags: azure, dns

We have own a domain name e.g mydomain.net and purchased a wildcard certificate *.mydomain.net from `App Service Domain` in `Azure`. All our azure websites are working fine with subdomain urls like `foo.mydomain.net`. Recently on a security review our root domain was flagged as MISMATCH SSL. When we type `mydomain.net` with `https`, we get an SSL warning `This server could not prove that it is mydomain.net; its security certificate is from *.azurewebsites.net.`

In azure DNS I do not see any URL records which can redirect the root domain to subdomain. Any idea how can we fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain a bit more.

```
mydomain.net is an application in azure. Correct?
foo.domain.net is a second application on azure?
foo2.domain.net is a third? etc?
```

How it should work.
Azure applications when uploading a website for example behind it there is an IIS.

So to make SSLs work correctly , you need to provide a pfx and upload it for each application

Also tell your application to work with SNI and bind with an SSL. This can by done with the SSL thumbprint.

My answer is kinda "messy" because your question is messy as well.
Let me know more, maybe I can help you.

Comment: `mydomain.net` is a domain name, `foo.mydomain.net` is a sub domain name. `foo.mydomain.net` is used as a custom domain name in azure web app. Applications are working fine without any SSL warning. Only issue is when we try to open the domain directly, it throws certificate error.

Comment: Provide me sceenshots please. Or not. Try adding me to your skype. fanosss@hotmail.com

Comment: SSL binding for azure app which uses the domain name as custom domain name was having some issues due to improper configuration. Thanks for your help.